# How to start tracking directories/files again which were removed from git index?

Tags: git, git-index

Using below command i removed few directories from git index:

```
git rm -r --cached <your directory>
```

Now how can i add those untracked directories to git index again?

Comment: Simply add them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them again to your index using `git add`:

```
git add <your directory>
```

Note that this will add all files, and not only those that were removed with your previous command. There is no way to only undo your command.